# Can't Share AppSync Ownership

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I'm new to AWS and am trying to use AppSync. I'd like to share access with my coworker, but I can't seem to get that to work. I've tried making an organization and adding him to it as well as enabling all the organization features.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up. I am on the AWS AppSync team and will follow up internally with a feature request on your behalf.